# Material Design / Materialize 3 column list

Tags: css, flexbox, material-design, materialize

I am looking into materialize - http://materializecss.com/

I need to create a list with 3 columns with equal separation but I cannot find any details on the documentation on how to do this.

I just need a basic list:

```
<ul>
<li>column 1</li> 
<li>column 2</li> 
<li>column 3</li> 
</ul>
```

So it looks like this:

```
column 1           column 2           column 3
```

How can i do this with Materialize or is this not a materialize thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `flex`

```css
ul{
display: flex;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
ul li{
list-style:none;
flex:1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>column 1</li> 
<li>column 2</li> 
<li>column 3</li> 
</ul>
```